# How long has the "situation" been going on by the beginning of episode 1?

Tags: gakkou-gurashi

Spoilers for episode 1:

> By the end of episode 1 of Gakkou Gurashi, we know that some sort of zombie apocalypse has happened, and that the girls are trapped in a section of the school that they've managed to barricade against zombie attack.
>
>  How long prior to episode 1 did the zombies first start appearing? Given their rations situation in episode 2, anywhere from days to months seems plausible.

Comment: I think there is no point in hiding the "zombie apocalypse" part of the series. Many summary of the series on the internet include it in the description.

Comment: @nhahtdh Well, those summaries are dumb, and I don't want to be part of the problem. The way episode 1 was shot makes it clear that we're _supposed_ to be surprised by the zombie reveal at the end. (I'll edit the title to be more descriptive when the show is done airing, but for now, I'd prefer to keep it this way.)

Comment: Crunchyroll did totally ruin the "surprise" with their description. (I was glad, though, 'cause I don't like zombies, so I didn't waste my time watching the show.) All the same, I agree with using spoiler tags, especially for parts of the question that will appear in the summary text on the main page.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57862/discussion-on-question-by-senshin-how-long-has-the-situation-been-going-on-by).